# Use one filter value to search and output several fields

Tags: sql, vba, forms, filter, field

Using Visual Basic.
Having searched and searched for an answer, my filter only selects from the 'Recipe' field. I'd like to input 'egg' into my txtSearch textbox and have my button give all recipes that have 'egg' in the recipe or as text in an ingredient. Currently only outputs 2 results: egg nog and eggs benedict. There are 15 recipes with egg in that I'd like to display, too.

```
Private Sub Search_Button_Click()

On Error GoTo Search_Button_Click_Err

Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "[Cocktail] like '*" & [Forms]![Find]![txtSearch] & "*'" & _
    " Or [Ing1] like '*" & [Forms]![Find]![txtSearch] & "*'" & _
    " Or [Ing2] like '*" & [Forms]![Find]![txtSearch] & "*'" & _
    " Or [Ing3] like '*" & [Forms]![Find]![txtSearch] & "*'" & _
    " Or [Ing4] like '*" & [Forms]![Find]![txtSearch] & "*'" & _
    " Or [Ing5] like '*" & [Forms]![Find]![txtSearch] & "*'" & _
    " Or [Ing6] like '*" & [Forms]![Find]![txtSearch] & "*'" & _
    " Or [Ing7] like '*" & [Forms]![Find]![txtSearch] & "*'"

If Len(strSQL) > 255 Then
   MsgBox "ApplyFilter string length exceeds 255 characters"

Else
   DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", strSQL

End If

Search_Button_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Search_Button_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Search_Button_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider clarifying the specific database you are using (SQL Server, MySQL etc) also the specific programming language (VB, C# etc). You can do this by using additional tags in your question.

Comment: Thank you, jmm312.

Answer (score 0):

an option is to concatenate all of the SQL fields that may contain what you're looking for then have that result in the where xxx like ....
Also some SQL environments use a % as a wildcard.